# no matching function for call to while passing array

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor

I am getting an error while writing a constructor which has some arguments to be passed. Searched previous threads but I am not getting it cleared.

Here is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int curr_state;
//int signal[3],trans_in[7],trans_fin[7],trans_sig[7];

class state_machine
{
        private :
                int start,end;
        public :
                state_machine(const int Q[],const int signals[],const int trans[][10][10],const int start,const int end);
//              int mystate();
                int run();
                int get_signal( );

                int get_state();
                int change_state();
};

state_machine::state_machine(const int Q[],const int signals[],const int trans[][10][10],const int start,const int end)
{
}     

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{   
        state_machine s;
        int Q[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
        int signals[3]={0,1,2};
        int trans[][3][1]={{1,0,2},{1,1,0},{1,2,0},{2,0,3},{2,1,0},{2,2,0},{3,0,5},{3,1,4},{3,2,2},{4,0,2},{4,1,0},{4,2,0},{5,0,0},{5,1,0},{5,2,0}};
        int start=1,end=5;
        //s.state_machine(Q,signals,trans,start,end);
}
```

Getting output as :

```
state_machine.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:<br>
state_machine.cpp:27:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘state_machine::state_machine()’<br>
state_machine.cpp:21:1: note: candidates are: state_machine::state_machine(const int*, const int*, const int (*)[10][10], int, int)<br>
state_machine.cpp:8:1: note:                 state_machine::state_machine(const state_machine&)
```

Comment: I have used the const keyword in the above constructor as after searching some threads they asked to do so but it didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: try changing int trans[][10][10] to int ***trans;

Comment: @Manoj<br>will ***trans store the data similat to that of trans[][][]. If yes then what would be the advantage ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor for `state_machine` expects an `int trans[][10][10]`. This must be matched by the type of the `trans` array in main.

You must change your main to

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int Q[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int signals[3]={0,1,2};
    int trans[][10][10]={{1,0,2},{1,1,0},{1,2,0},{2,0,3},{2,1,0},{2,2,0},{3,0,5},{3,1,4},{3,2,2},{4,0,2},{4,1,0},{4,2,0},{5,0,0},{5,1,0},{5,2,0}};
    int start=1,end=5;
    state_machine s(Q,signals,trans,start,end);
    return 0;
}
```

Although the initializer list for `trans` doesn't fit the required type.

Comment: yes that is exactly what was required along with the below comment of user1872084.Thanks both of you

Answer (score 1):

Your 3D arrays sizes that you specified needs to match **exactly**, which it does not. As the error says it is expecting `const int (*)[10][10]`

if `int trans[][3][1]` became `int trans[][10][10]` this error will go away

Comment: yes this changes was certainly required also an call was required to the constructor from main. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

First of all you cannot create `state_machine s;` as no body for ctor w/o parameters are available.

Secondly, you need to call last line as `state_machine s(Q,signals,trans,start,end);`

Thirdly, 3rd parameter passing for ctor is incorrect. for 3d array, indexes should match. make `int trans[][3][1]` to `int trans[][10][10]` or vice-versa.

Comment: hi, I didnt get ur 1st comment "First of all you cannot create state_machine s; as no body for ctor w/o parameters are available." Suppose if there was some code written inside the constructor mainly initializing the parameters then would have it been valid ?

Comment: ohh..I got it. It a initialization of the Object along with call to constructor. Thanks

Comment: Correct...since you are not passing any argument with "state_machine s" call, so it will try to call ctor without parameters which is not available in your code.